# split string then insert records in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table emp with fields are id,name,salary,dept.
I want to create a procedure to insert records in that emp table.

In that procedure only one string is a parameter.

string = 1$shubham$1000$comp#2$vijay$5000$civil#33$ram$23456$mech#......

then in emp tableinsert records like 
id  |  name  |  salary  |  dept
1      shubham  1000       comp
2      vijay     5000      civil
33     ram      23456      mech

The row are seperated by '#' any column value are seperated by '$' and
If given records are already present then update that records based on emp ID i.e emp ID is the primary key in that table.

below procedure not provied right output to me.

```
create or replace procedure proc_one_stack_DUP ( string_in in varchar2 )


IS 

limit_a varchar2(1000);
v_id number(10);
v_name varchar2(1000);
v_salary varchar2(1000);
v_dept varchar2(1000);

v_one  varchar2(100);

pos_id number(10);
pos_name number(10);
pos_salary number(10);
pos_dept number(10);

counter number(10);
string_1 varchar2(1000);
len_all number(10);
len_copy  number(10);
a1 number(10);
begin 


len_copy:=0;
pos_id := 1;
counter := 0;

len_all:=length(string_in);



limit_a := REGEXP_COUNT (string_in, '#');

for i in 1..limit_a
loop 


string_1 := substr(string_in,counter+1,INSTR (string_in,'#')-1);
 a1 := length(string_1);

--for k in 1..1
--loop

v_id := substr(string_1,pos_id,INSTR (string_1,'$')-1);
pos_id := length(v_id);

v_name := substr(string_1,pos_id+2,INSTR (string_1,'$',1,2)-pos_id-1-1);
pos_name := length(v_name);

v_salary := substr(string_1,pos_name+pos_id+3,INSTR (string_1,'$',1,3)-pos_name-pos_id-1-2);
pos_salary := length(v_salary);

v_dept := substr(string_1,pos_salary+pos_id+pos_name+4,INSTR (string_1,'#')-pos_name-pos_id-pos_salary-1-3); -- INSTR (string_1,'#')-1
pos_dept := length(v_dept);

insert into emp values (v_id,v_name,v_salary,v_dept);
commit;

--end loop;  

counter := counter+a1+1;

end loop;

end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use one select statement where your string must be split into desired columns as following:

```
SQL> DROP TABLE EMP;

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE EMP (
  2      ID       NUMBER,
  3      NAME     VARCHAR2(10),
  4      SALARY   NUMBER,
  5      DEPT     VARCHAR2(10)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> DEFINE P_INPUT_STRING = '1$shubham$1000$comp#2$vijay$5000$civil#33$ram$23456$mech#';
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO EMP
  2      SELECT
  3          REGEXP_SUBSTR(INP, '[^$]+', 1, 1) AS ID,
  4          REGEXP_SUBSTR(INP, '[^$]+', 1, 2) AS NAME,
  5          REGEXP_SUBSTR(INP, '[^$]+', 1, 3) AS SALARY,
  6          REGEXP_SUBSTR(INP, '[^$]+', 1, 4) AS DEPT
  7      FROM
  8          (
  9              SELECT
 10                  REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM('#' FROM '&p_input_string'), '[^#]+', 1, LEVEL) AS INP
 11              FROM
 12                  DUAL
 13              CONNECT BY
 14                  LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(TRIM('#' FROM '&p_input_string'), '#')
 15          );

2 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM EMP;

        ID NAME           SALARY DEPT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 shubham          1000 comp
         2 vijay            5000 civil

SQL>
```

Cheers!!